# Partition refinement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be the infinite set of natural numbers and let $P$ be a partition made of two blocks, all the even numbers and all the odd numbers.

Does it exist a partition $S$ of $U$ such that $P$ is a refinement of $S$ and $S$ is not {{$U$}}?

Comment: $P$ is a refinement of $P$, but other than that, no, since a proper refinement has strictly more blocks, and thus $S$ must have cardinality at most $1$ if it is a proper refinement.

Comment: Thanks for the definition "proper refinement has strictly more blocks": do you have a source for the definition or is there a proof of it?

Comment: Try to prove it. It's a rather trivial consequence of the definition.

Comment: If P is a proper refinement of S, then there is an element of S such that it is not equivalent to any element of P. Since every element of P is equal or included in an element of S, then P must have an higher cardinality then P?

Comment: @Don Thousand in case I wanted to find more info on partitions and refinement, are there online resources?

Comment: depends on what applications of them you care about. They are a tool used in a large number of areas of math.

Comment: I was looking for topics related to set theory